# This is a little vague, but in a general sense how demanding is calculating an exponential equation in say, python or java?

Tags: java, python

Say I wanted to continually calculate the derivative of a point as it moves across the x-axis of the graph of y = sq rt x.

The derivative would be: [1/x^(1/2)] *  (1/2)

If a program were to calculate that 10 times a second as the point traveled across x, how demanding would that be? So the values of x could be 1.7, 1.8, 2, 2.1, 2.21, etc... would this calculation use too much computational power if it was just an extremely super tiny aspect of a much much larger program?

Comment: You're aware that the graph of y = sqrt(x) doesn't cross the X-axis, right?  It ends at (0,0).

Comment: In Python, the cost of the `**` operator is roughly on the same order as the cost of iterating one step in a loop, so it's not going to matter at all. (Unless you're doing it in NumPy, in which case it might become relevant.) In Java, you can time it, but I'll bet it's still less than an order of magnitude slower than the loop itself, so you're still probably OK for most apps.

Comment: By the way, you _probably_ know this, but just in case: the `^` operator doesn't mean power in either Java or Python; it means bitwise XOR. Also, `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`, in Java and Python 2 (but not Python 3).

Comment: Yeah I know, in my conceptual program the x value would never get to zero.

Comment: Assuming you've got `x` and `y` for some point already, and `y = sqrt(x)`, why don't you calculate `1 / 2y` instead of `1 / 2 sqrt(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just performed a [JMH MicroBenchMark](http://java-performance.info/jmh/) of the following Java code on my i7 laptop with random values of `x` for you:

```
public double test()
{
    return (1.0 / Math.pow(x, 0.5)) * 0.5; 
}
```

and the result is:

```
Benchmark        Mode    Samples        Mean      Mean Error    Units

Benchmark.test   thrpt     10     12122497.328   106601.475     ops/s
```

That is, over 12 million operations per second, give or take an error of 1 million per second.

So if you want to do 10 per second, you should be alright.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This exactly the you're of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Obviously mileage may vary on different machines but in essence on modern hardware drawing a GUI would require far more CPU time than a little bit of maths.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the numbers involved, but on a modern computer I would not describe [`Math.pow(double, double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) as particularly computationally intense.

Answer (score 1):

These timings should give you an idea of how fast python is:

```
In [1]: from math import sqrt

In [2]: %timeit sqrt(123)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 125 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit 1./(2*sqrt(123))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 235 ns per loop

In [4]: def f(x): return 1./(2*sqrt(x))

In [5]: %timeit f(456)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 384 ns per loop
```

So a modern processor can evaluate a function like `f(x)` about 2.5 million times per second.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you so much. This clears a lot up for me.